# Pass ssh-agent to dockerfile to install private repository modules

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm

I am trying to automate a docker build in Jenkins pipeline. In my dockerfile, I basically build a node application. In my npm install, I have some private git repositories which need os bindings and so have to be installed in the container. When I run this manually, I transfer my ssh keys (id_rsa) to dockerfile which is used for doing npm install. Now, my problem is when running this task in jenkins pipeline, I will be configuring a ssh-agent(Jenkins plugin). It will not be possible to extract private key from ssh-agent. How should I pass my ssh-agent to my dockerfile.

EDIT 1:

I got it partially working by this:

```
Docker Build Command:
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --no-cache -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$IMAGE_NAME:v$BUILD_NUMBER --ssh default . &&
```

Then in Docker file:

This works fine:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvvT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" 
git clone git@github.com:****
```

Weird thing is this doesn't work:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvvT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" npm install git+ssh//git@github.com:****
```

I feel this is something to do with `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Comment: you could maybe forward your ssh key as secret string and using docker environment variables. Then in your docker scripts rely on that env var to setup your npm ssh requirements at runtime.

Comment: @boly38 Edited the original question based on progress today.

Comment: what is "npm install git" ? do you mean "git clone && npm install" instead?

Comment: @boly38 No actually this command basically installs a package from a private git repo. So the command will be npm install git+ssh://github.com/path/to/repo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally got it working by using ROOT user in Dockerfile and setting the npm cache to root.
The problem was that git was using the `/root/.ssh` folder while npm was using a different path - `/home/.ssh` as it's npm cache was set on `/home/.ssh`

For anyone still struggling, this is the config I used

Docker Build Command:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --no-cache -t test --ssh default .
```

Dockerfile:

```
USER root

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        openssh-server \
        openssh-client
RUN mkdir -p -m 600 /root/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts && echo "Host *\n  StrictHostKeyChecking no" > /root/.ssh/config
RUN echo "Check ssh_config" && cat /root/.ssh/config
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm config set cache /root
RUN --mount=type=ssh GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvvT" npm install
```

Comment: I have been beating my head against this for a day now, and this worked! Thank you.